Doubt on exercise on finite Von Neumann Algebras
I am doing the following exercise: Let $M \subseteq B(\mathbb{H})$ be a von Neumann algebra, $\tau$ be a faithful, tracial, normal state $\tau: M \to \mathbb{C}$. Prove that M is finite. What happens if $\tau$ is not normal?
Here there is the definition the professor used for normality: $M$ von Neumann algebra is said to be normal if it is WOT-continuous on $M_1 \equiv \{ x \in M : ||x || \leq1 \}$.
Here is my proof: M is finite if and only if the identity $\mathbb{I}$ is finite, or, equivalently, if and only if every isometry $v \in M$ is also unitary. Given $v$ isometry, we have $v^* v = \mathbb{I}$ and we need to prove that also $v v^* = \mathbb{I}$. Then let's consider $\tau(\mathbb{I} - v v^*) = \tau(\mathbb{I}) - \tau(v v^*) = \tau(\mathbb{I}) - \tau(v^* v) = \tau(\mathbb{I} - v^* v) = 0$, where I used the tracial properties of $\tau$. Then, since $\tau$ is also faithful, we have that $\tau(\mathbb{I} - v v^*) = 0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{I} - v v^* = 0$. It seems that normality is not necessary, but I suspect that it is not correct. Where is the error above? What did I miss?

There is no error. Your proof is correct. The existence of a faithful tracial state implies the algebra is finite. Normality is not necessary in the first place.

There is no error. Normality is irrelevant here.
